# Can I add a term to the Lagrangian calculation in Pyomo/PySP?

Tags: pyomo

I would like to use Pyomo's PySP framework to do some stochastic optimization. In this model, I have some variables that must be the same across scenarios (i.e., the standard root node variables). As part of the Progressive Hedging approach, PySP creates an augmented Lagrangian, whose multipliers are adjusted iteratively until all these variables are equal across scenarios. All good so far. But I also have some constraints that must be enforced on an expected value basis. In the extensive form, these look like this:

```
sum(probability[s] * use[s] for s in scenarios) == resource
```

This complicating constraint could be factored out with a Lagrangian relaxation. This would require adding a term like this to the main objective function (which would then become part of each scenario's objective function):

```
(
    lambda * (sum(probability[s] * use[s] for s in scenarios) - resource) 
    + mu/2 * (sum(probability[s] * use[s] for s in scenarios) - resource)**2
)
```

This is very similar to the Lagrangian terms for the nonanticipativity constraints that are already in the main objective function. At each iteration, the PySP framework automatically updates the multipliers for the nonanticipativity terms and then propagates their values into the individual scenarios.

So my question is, is there some way to add my terms to the standard Lagrangian managed by PySP, and have it automatically update my multipliers along with its own? I don't mind doing some heavy lifting, but I can't find any detailed documentation on how PySP is implemented, so I'm not sure where to start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The PH implementation in PySP supports some level of customization through the use of user-defined extensions. These are classes you can implement whose methods are called by PH at different points in the algorithm. You can tell PH to use an extension by setting the command-line option "--user-defined-extension" to a file that contains an implementation. A number of examples can be found [here](https://github.com/Pyomo/pyomo/tree/master/pyomo/pysp/plugins) (look for files that contain IPHExtension and copy what they do).

Unfortunately, there is not any specific code that will make what you want to do easy. You will have to look at source code to see how PH updates and manages these objective parameters (see [ph.py](https://github.com/Pyomo/pyomo/blob/master/pyomo/pysp/ph.py) for this and to see where different extension methods are called in the algorithm).

Comment: Thanks for these pointers! `ph.py` has a lot going on, but I eventually figured out that I can do this by creating a plugin that sets `ph._ph_weight_updates_enabled` to `False` during `post_iteration_0_solves`, and then calculates values for all the weights in `post_asynchronous_var_w_update` or `post_iteration_k_solve_solves`. (This will need to reproduce the effect of `ph.ProgressiveHedging.update_weights` and/or `ph.ProgressiveHedging.update_weights_for_scenario`.) The `exsteincombettesextension.py` plugin gives an example of this. Looks like tricky work, but I'll get to it eventually!